# Change selected nodes style, d3.js Drag and drop collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have successfully build the d3.js collapsible drag and drop tree, I want to add one more functionality of restricting to drop node to some selected nodes i have done this functionality too, i want to change the style/ class of selected node if they are restricted.

```
if (selectedNode) {
                if ((selectedNode.id != 5) || (draggingNode.id != 1)) {
                    // now remove the element from the parent, and insert it into the new elements children
                    var index = draggingNode.parent.children.indexOf(draggingNode);
                    if (index > -1) {
                        draggingNode.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined' || typeof selectedNode._children !== 'undefined') {
                        if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined') {
                            selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
                        } else {
                            selectedNode._children.push(draggingNode);
                        }
                    } else {
                        selectedNode.children = [];
                        selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
                    }
                    // Make sure that the node being added to is expanded so user can see added node is correctly moved
                    expand(selectedNode);
                    sortTree();
                    endDrag();
                }
                else { var k= d3.select(selectedNode); return; endDrag(); }
            } else {
                endDrag();
            }
```

I had done changes in above function but i want to change the style of selected node if it's invalid move. Please suggest me how can i change the style of circle in above section

Comment: `selectedNode.style(...)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response.. selectedNode.style is not working getting error : "Object #<Object> has no method 'style' "

Comment: Could you show us the complete code please, in particular the context in which that fragment you've posted appears?

Comment: selectedNode.style("fill-opacity", 0);  and selectedNode.style("fill", "blue");

Comment: For the code in the question please. In particular, what is `selectedNode`?

Comment: Hi Lars, I followed this plugin for dragging and dropping the node http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033  : I would suggest please review it, SelectedNode is a variable on which another (dragging node) is going to connect.

Comment: Sounds like `d3.select(this).style(...)` should work.

Comment: It's changed the text color of dragging node (A node which is going to connect) instead of selected node (parent node). I wanted to change the style of selected node circle to show something like connection on this node is not valid.

Comment: Hmmm, `svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").data([selectedNode], function(d) { return d.id; }).style(...)`?

Comment: Ok, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you're working with has only a reference to the data of the selected node, not the DOM element. This makes it slightly trickier to access the node to be able to set a style on it, but you can do it using D3's data matching mechanism:

```
var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").data([selectedNode], function(d) { return d.id; });
node.style(...);
```